# Switching from Line to Mesh Geometry in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

I'm getting a error relating to the bufferGeometry in three.js when I try and make a boolean function that changes a geometry from line to mesh.

```
        if (value == true){
            scene.remove(shape);
            shape = new THREE.Line(genGeometry, lineMaterial);
            scene.add(shape);
        }
        else{
            scene.remove(shape);
            shape = new THREE.Mesh(genGeometry, meshBasicMaterial);
            scene.add(shape);           
        }
```

Is there maybe a better way I should approach this?  Or maybe someone could explain this bug

```
                for ( var i = 0,l = geometryGroupsList.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                    addBuffer( _webglObjects, geometryGroupsList[ i ], object );

                }
```

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Where did u declared geometryGroupsList ?

Comment: I didn't it was in the THREE.js

Comment: MB u include someone bad, cos ur  geometryGroupsList == undefined, try to console.log(geometryGroupsList) before for()

Comment: It is undefined but I'm  not calling geometryGroupsList  (and my initial geometry does appear in the scene)  -- it's getting called in three

Comment: for ( var i = 0,l = geometryGroupsList.length; i < l; i ++ ) {}  u called it here

Comment: I think I found the problem -- I'm reassigning the geometry inside the render loop.